# pyqtSlot() and return type python list

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to use pyqtSlot() decorator in order to expose a python function to javascript code.
The return type is list so i should write:
@pyqtSlot(result=list)
But i get an error:
"TypeError: unable to convert a Python 'list' object to a C++ 'PyQt_PyObject' instance"

I made some research but yet couldnt find an answer.
According to pyqt doc i can return any python type object or a string specifying a C++ type, so i tried result='array'.
But it doesnt work or i do something wrong.

```
@pyqtSlot(result=list)
def getCodeList(self):
    return self.codeList
```

Comment: I didn't think you could return results from a slot...

Comment: it is a must in pyqtSlot() decorator.
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

Answer (score 9):

I think i found a way.
I just wrap python list with QVariant() and return QVariant.

```
@pyqtSlot(result=QVariant)
def getCodeList(self):
    return QVariant(self.codeList)
```

Thanks QVariant.

Comment: how you convert QVariant into list later?

Comment: i dont need to convert.it just works.
but if i'll try to understand why according my little knowledge.. pyqtSlot decorator is made in order to pass result into C++ which is the language Qt is written in.
so list type in python is turned to an array type of C++ using QVariant.
and all that is made so QtWebkit bridge technology can expose code written in C++(or python using decorator pyqtSlot) to javascript code.
all what i wrote is not 100% sure.
so take it with caution.